# Is there a way to solve or bypass the type error using dynamic env variables with TypeORM and TypeScripts?

Tags: typescript, express, typeorm

I'm working on a back-end project using TsED framework (it's basically using TypeScript and ExpressJS)

I also installed the dot-env package to use custom environment variables (from a .env file at the root of my project) to work with TypeORM.

I successfully have access to my environment variables, everything is working fine but if you set dynamically the TypeORM's type to 'mysql' it's returning the following error:

> The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'ConnectionOptions'.

I had similar issues, especially with the TypeORM's 'logging' option, but I managed to solve them by casting the .env variables retrieved in my config.js file.

What I did so far to try to solve the TypeORM's 'type' option is :

- Casting my .env variable to DatabaseType, but it still returns the same error,
- Casting my .env variable to 'any' type but it then returns an undefined variable,

I really have no idea on what's going on. Even if I hard code the 'mysql' value instead of retrieving the .env value, it still throw an error. The following code snippets show my config and .env content, and the image shows the error.

```html
# DATABASE (.env file)
DB_TYPE=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123456
DB_NAME=taskline
DB_PORT=3306
DB_SYNCHRONIZE=false
DB_LOGGING=true
```

```js
   

 // config.js file retrieving my .env variables
    import * as env from 'dotenv';
    import { LoggerOptions } from 'typeorm/logger/LoggerOptions';
    env.config();

    const config = {
        "DB_DRIVER": 'mysql',
        "DB_HOST": process.env.DB_HOST,
        "DB_USERNAME": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        "DB_PASSWORD": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        "DB_NAME": process.env.DB_NAME,
        "DB_PORT": parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) as number,
        "DB_SYNCHRONIZE": Boolean(process.env.DB_SYNCHRONIZE) as boolean,
        "DB_LOGGING": process.env.DB_LOGGING as LoggerOptions
    };

    export { config };
```

[The returned error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gIP8.png)

I would like to know why this error occurs and how I could solve or bypass it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TypeOrm driver connection option can be overwritten using type `any` as follows.

```
const DB_DRIVER: any = process.env.DB_DRIVER || 'mysql';

const config = {
    "DB_DRIVER": DB_DRIVER,
    "DB_HOST": process.env.DB_HOST,
    "DB_USERNAME": process.env.DB_USERNAME,
    "DB_PASSWORD": process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    "DB_NAME": process.env.DB_NAME,
    "DB_PORT": parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT) as number,
    "DB_SYNCHRONIZE": Boolean(process.env.DB_SYNCHRONIZE) as boolean,
    "DB_LOGGING": process.env.DB_LOGGING as LoggerOptions
};
```